# calling a different python interpreter from bash command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, python, google-app-engine

I have python 2.7 installed

```
[user@localhost google_appengine]$ python  
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:03:06)   
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I want to use the python 2.5.2 that is in this directory

```
[user@localhost Downloads]$ ls |grep "Python-2*"  
Python-2.5.2
Python-2.5.2.tgz
```

to run a python script in Khan Academy platform against a google app engine application

```
sudo python sample_data.py -a ~/workspace/GAE/google_appengine/appcfg.py upload
```

Currently, when running the last script 2.7 python complains a lot (Google App Engine runs on 2.5.2 mostly and 2.6 almost)

I would like to do something like

```
sudo python env set ~/Downloads/Python-2.5.2 sample_data.py -a ~/workspace/GAE/google_appengine/appcfg.py upload
```

Is this possible? If yes, please point the way. If not, please suggest a way to call python2.5.2 WITHOUT having to uninstall python 2.7

many many thanks
Dennis

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Python 2.5.2 installed or the binaries, just use the full path to the binary:

```
sudo ~/Downloads/python
```

instead of `sudo python`

Without providing the full path, you are running the binary that `bash` finds on the `$PATH` environment variable.

Also check [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/inst/search-path.html), specially the part about `$PYTHONHOME` and `$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I don't know Python, but you may have to have PYTHON_HOME or something similar set before execution, and maybe even a PATH change.  All pretty simple, especially if you do this in a short script, but you may need to track down multiple references.

Comment: Thanks @mpez I edited my answer including the environment vars.